# Opening a link in Chrome Custom Tabs using the Automate app on Android

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm trying to make a flow that opens a site I use for work and performs some actions automatically, but I can't figure out how to open the link in chrome custom tabs.

I've tried using each and every chrome activity that contains the words "custom tabs" and putting my link in the data URI box, which works to open links in chrome (for the main chrome activity) but all I'm getting is errors.

On a related note, how come some websites open in custom tabs when added to home screen and others don't?

Thanks!